# How can I add a property to Object.prototype without it being applied to Number.prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, defineproperty

My goal is to create a **master_script.js**.  A handler file mainly used in development.

A subsection of this file is dedicated to customizing the prototypes of the foundation objects:

> 1. String
> 2. Number
> 3. Array
> 4. Object
> 5. Date
> 6. Function
> 7. Boolean

So as I'm writing out my code blocks...

```
/********************************************************/
Object.defineProperty(
    Number.prototype,'len',
    {get:function(){
        str=this.toString()
        return str.length
    }}
)
/********************************************************/
n=123
o={123:'abc',abc:123}
/********************************************************/
console.log(
    'n              ⇒ ',n,
    '\n n.len       ⇒ ',n.len,
    '\n n.__proto__ ⇒ ',n.__proto__
)
/********************************************************/
```

Works fine!

- when I expand `n.__proto__` in the **console** it displays the `len: (...)` property and it's getter function `get len: function (){`.
- and when I type `n.` into the **console** it is clearly visible on the list of properties|methods.

The problems start when I configure the same setup for the `o` variable:

```
/********************************************************/
Object.defineProperty(
    Number.prototype,'len',
    {get:function(){
        str=this.toString()
        return str.length
    }}
)
/******************************/
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype,'len',
    {get:function(){
        cnt=0
        for(i in this)  cnt++;
        return cnt
    }}
)
/********************************************************/
n=123
o={123:'abc',abc:123}
/********************************************************/
console.log(
    'n              ⇒ ',n,
    '\n n.len       ⇒ ',n.len,
    '\n n.__proto__ ⇒ ',n.__proto__
)
/******************************/
console.log(
    'o              ⇒ ',o,
    '\n o.len       ⇒ ',o.len,
    '\n o.__proto__ ⇒ ',o.__proto__
)
/********************************************************/
```

The first thing I notice is that when I now type `n.` or `o.` into the **console** the popup list of properties|methods no longer contains a reference to the `len` property, but if I type in the full extension `n.len` or `o.len` I get the desired result of `3` or `2`...

So I know the code is legit but I need the **console** popup as there is about 40 different properties & methods for each of the 7 foundation objects...

So I wrote a test block to try & identify the problem:

```
/********************************************************/
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype,'dis',
    {get:function(){return this}}
)
/******************************/
Object.defineProperty(
    Number.prototype,'len',
    {get:function(){return this.length}}
)
/********************************************************/
o={123:'abc',abc:123}
n=123
e=document.createElement('option')
/********************************************************/
console.log(
    'o              ⇒ ',o,
    '\n o.__proto__ ⇒ ',o.__proto__
)
/******************************/
console.log(
    'n              ⇒ ',n,
    '\n n.__proto__ ⇒ ',n.__proto__
)
/******************************/
console.log(
    'e              ⇒ ',e,
    '\n e.__proto__ ⇒ ',e.__proto__
)
/********************************************************/
```

Immediately after expanding the `.__proto__` in the **console** for `o`, `n` and now `e`, I noticed that all 3 had been given the `dis` property I had originally tried to assign to solely the `o` object.

Then I cracked it: `Number.prototype` itself is an object, ergo it inherits the `dis` property from the `Object.prototype`

How can I append the `dis` property solely to the `o` object without it being inherited by `n` from `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Wow. That is one *long* question. Am I correct in narrowing it down to **How can I add a property to Object.prototype without it being applied to Number.prototype**?

Comment: All built–in constructor prototypes inherit from Object.prototype, so no surprise that properties added to it turn up on other objects. That's the reason modifying Object.prototype has been seen as a bad idea for a very long time.

Comment: yeah sorry @RGraham ur correct, I just thought a bit of case history would help yz understand what I'm tryin to achieve, I'm tryin to avoid the simple solutions I've already tried like the first answer below...

Comment: @RobG: I kinda knew this already! Thing is I'm just learning why it's sooooo true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A subsection of this file is dedicated to customizing the prototypes of the foundation objects

Oy vey. Not the greatest idea IMHO. Especially modifying the `Object` prototype. Yeesh.

> So I know the code is legit but I need the console popup as there is about 40 different properties & methods for each of the 7 foundation objects...

Why? Are you doing your development in a browser console?

> Do you have the nous to show me how to append the dis property solely to the o object without it being inherited by n from Object.prototype?

Ok...

```
Object.defineProperty(
    o, 'dis',
    { get:function(){ return this; } }
);
```

How's that?

Anything you add to the `Object` prototype is going to show up on pretty much *everything* (that's why it's a bad idea).

Since `o` *only* inherits from `Object`, there's no way to define a property that would only show up on plain objects and not on everything else. Your choices are to:

- Define the property directly on `o`, or
- Instead of using a plain object for `o`, create `o` from your own custom type and put your property on the prototype of that custom type (much better than modifying the built-in types' prototypes).

---

**Note:** Of course, you could modify `Number.prototype` to have a `dis` property of `undefined`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'dis', {
    value: void 0
});

console.log((9).dis);
```

That would solve your problem as far as numbers go, but that `dis` property is still going to be on pretty much everything else in existence.

And please, for goodness' sake, use semicolons. Think of the children.

Comment: geesh @JLRishe, you sound like the professor offov the simpsons in yer openin statement. lol. I do get what ur sayin, but the solutions you propose still discount the availability of being able to request `{}.len` on any object being used in js... the original __ms.js__ `.len` code was `ms.len(obj)`, `obj.len` just seemed tidier. Any other workarounds welcome tho!

Comment: ps.  ***Why? Are you doing your development in a browser console?***  I'm not, but I am using the console to more clearly view the objects properties I'm adding by simply extending the object in the console rather than writing a code block to list all properties.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
/********************************************************
⇒   create the master objects.
/********************************************************/
function MasterObject(dis){
    Object.defineProperty(
        this,'this_object',
        {get:function(){return dis}}
    )
}
/******************************/
function MasterArray(dis){
    Object.defineProperty(
        this,'this_array',
        {get:function(){return dis}}
    )
}
/********************************************************
⇒   define the master properties.
/********************************************************/
Object.defineProperty(
    Object.prototype,'_',
    {get:function(){return new MasterObject(this)}}
)
/******************************/
Object.defineProperty(
    Array.prototype,'_',
    {get:function(){return new MasterArray(this)}}
)
/********************************************************
⇒   example to expand in the console.
/********************************************************/
x={a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5}
y=[]
    y['a']=1
    y['b']=2
    y['c']=3
    y['d']=4
    y['e']=5
z=[x,y]
/********************************************************
⇒   open the console, type [z], hit [enter] and expand...
/********************************************************/
```

Rundown:

- Let's say for example we define a property on `Object.prototype` called `len` & set its value to `5`.
- Now if we call `{}.len`, we get a result of 5 & if we call `[].len` or `"".len` or `#.len` etc, we get the same result due to inheritance from `Object.prototype` on instantiation.
- But let's say we then define a property on `Array.prototype` with the same name:- `len` & set its value to `50`.
- Now if we call `{}.len` etc, we get the same result of 5, but if we call `[].len` we get 50, as the `Array.prototype` was created most recently and its definition of `len` overwrites `Object.prototype`'s version.

Solution:

- So if we define only 1 property to `Object.prototype` called for simplicity's sake `_`,  & set its value to a substructure object that contains the handlers specific to *objects* only.
- Then if we do the same for `Array.prototype`, but set the value of this `_` property to another substructure that contains handlers specific to *arrays* only.
- Then as with the `.len` property in the rundown above `Array.prototype`'s version of `_` overwrites `Object.prototype`'s version ergo we have 2 completely individual `_` properties with no miscellaneous inheritances.

Drawbacks:

- Can no longer access the properties the easy way `{}.len`, it now has to be prefixed `{}._.len`.

Benefits:

- When defining properties on `Object.prototype` the whole task can become a paradoxical nightmare, where even errors thrown to the console inherit the properties, and if you've added 100 new properties|methods to `Object.prototype` then each is visible when you expand any error in the console!
- This method ensures that only 1 property is ever visible `_`, and that property is customizable to the type of owner object.

Expansion:

- I'm looking into modifying this code to accommodate the varying objects that do **NOT** conform to this standard, like maybe a handler for:

```
x=document.getElementsByTagName('td')
y=x._.len
```

Like:

```
function MasterObject(dis){
    if(dis.constructor.name=='HTMLCollection'){
        Object.defineProperty(
            this,'len',
            {get:function(){
                cnt=0
                for(ia in dis) cnt++;
                return cnt
            }}
        )
    }
        else{
            Object.defineProperty(
                this,'this_object',
                {get:function(){return dis}}
            )
        }
}
```

So `x._.len` would be available to any list of objects but not say `{a:1}` as this has a `constructor.name` of `object` not `HTMLCollection`.

This is a pet project. It's only in its own prototype phase and I'm looking for ideas on how to expand this concept, from those with experience on the topic, before I either go back to the old ways or break through this stigma surrounding prototype modification and come up with a new more efficient way!